# Fastest way of filling a combobox from a datatable in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

The data table in the following code is filled with 7500-+ records. This all loads quickly from the server. The problem is that it takes a while to loop through the data rows to add them to the combo box. Is there any alternative way of setting the data source of the combo box or a way of speeding this process up?

```
        Dim dtColours As New DataTable
        Dim daColours As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim i As Integer

        ConnectToSQL()
        daColours = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Rtrim(UPPER(Colour)) As Colour FROM invStockColour WHERE InUse = 1 ORDER BY Colour", dbSQL)
        daColours.Fill(dtColours)

        For i = 0 To dtColours.Rows.Count - 1
            cboColours.Items.Add(dtColours.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
        Next

        dbSQL.Close()
```

Comment: This looks like a nice method to add the data. 7500+ items in a ComboBox sounds like too much. Maybe you can split the information and load into the combobox less data depending on user selecing values on another combobox or something like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fasted way would be to use the `AddRange` method instead of using `Add`, something like:

```
Dim items = dtColours.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(d) DirectCast(d(0).ToString(), Object)).ToArray()
cboColours.Items.AddRange(items)
```

I did a simple check and using `AddRange` is ~3x faster than using `Add`.

Of course allocating an array and filling it with a `For` loop would probably some milliseconds faster than using Linq.

Comment: It seems like you are right. And as far as you are already accounting for the LINQ part too, I guess that I will better delete my answer.

Comment: PS: regarding your last edit: I am not a fan of LINQ (most of the times prefer looping) but, in this context (an unclearly big DataTable), I would go for LINQ.

Comment: @varocarbas Linq is very nice, but the syntax for anonymous methods in VB.Net is soooooo ugly :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim daColours As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Rtrim(UPPER(Colour)) As Colour FROM invStockColour WHERE InUse = 1 ORDER BY Colour", dbSQL)

Dim dtColours As New DataTable
daColours.Fill(dtColours)

cboColours.DataSource=dtColours  
cboColours.DisplayMember="Colour"
```

Comment: please explain how your code achieves the goal the OP is reaching for.  this may seem obvious to you and other experienced programmers.  If you provide clear explanation of your code it will lead to better answers on SO and also more upvotes

Answer (score 4):

You could also bind your ComboBox DataSource property to the DataTable.  This has the added advantage of binding other column data (such as key values you might not want the user to see).

You should be able to return a DataTable object from your SQLAdapter.

```
cboColours.DataSource = dtColours
cboColours.DisplayMember = dtColours.Columns("Colour").ToString
cboColours.ValueMember = dtColours.Columns("Colour_id").ToString
```

Comment: I prefer this method as I deal solely with classes that return datatables. This method also allows me to set the selectedvalue from a hidden index within a flexgrid in the Click method.

Comment: The control will bind when DataSource is set. Setting the ValueMember after the DataSource will cause the control to bind again. So as fast as it could be. DataSource should be set after ValueMember.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`cboColours.DataSource = dtColours 'For Windows Forms` or

`cboColours.ItemsSource = dtColours 'For WPF`

Comment: Firstly you should mention things like DisplayMember and ValueMember when suggesting setting the data source. In addition to that, this works no faster than what I am currently doing.