# Fill a ComboBox with a DataSet

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, dataset

I'm trying to use a DataSet, filled from a SQL Database, that have only one column with unique names to fill ComboBoxes with.

Right now I'm using this code:

```
ClassTables.FillDistrib()
ComboBox.DataSource = ClassTables.Distrib.Tables("Names")
```

`ClassTables` is a Class used to fill my DataSets.
`Distrib` is the name of my DataSet (`FillDistrib` is the Sub used to clear and fill it)
`ComboBox` is the name of my ComboBox

But the ComboBox droplist is left blank.
However, used in a DataGridView, it appears that the DataSet is filled correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way of filling a combobox from a datatable in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609175/fastest-way-of-filling-a-combobox-from-a-datatable-in-vb-net). Theres a few answers in that post that will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning a complex object as a `DataTable` to the [DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.datasource?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.DataSource);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) property of ComboBox or ListBox controls, specify, using the [DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.DisplayMember);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) property, which **`Column`** of the DataTable should be used as source to display the text of the ListControl Items.

If the selected item should also return a value different from the text displayed, also set the [ValueMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.ValueMember);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) property to the name of the Column that provides the associated values.
Possibly, before setting the Control's DataSource reference (to avoid redundant iterations of the underlying data).

Let's build a `DataTable` to test the procedure:

Assign a `DataTable` to the `DataSource` of a ComboBox control, specifying as the  `DisplayMember` the name of the Column that provides the text to display and as `ValueMember` the name of the Column that provides additional data that will be returned by the **`ComboBox.SelectedValue`** property when a user changes the **`SelectedItem`**:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable("TestTable")
dt.Columns.AddRange({
    New DataColumn("Names", GetType(String)), 
    New DataColumn("Values", GetType(Integer))
})

Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
dt.Rows.Add({"Some Name", 1})
dt.Rows.Add({"Some OtherName Jr.", 2})
dt.Rows.Add({"Another Name", 3})
dt.Rows.Add({"Last Name", 4})

ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Names"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Values"
ComboBox1.DataSource = dt

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim cbo = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    TextBox1.Text = cbo.GetItemText(cbo.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]