# How to populate a combobox and then subsequetly search and set the index

Tags: vb.net, combobox

This should not be that difficult, but apparently this old dog doesn't understand (or can't figure out).  I have a combobox that has a list of states (cb_States).  The data for the states is being read from an Access database.  I have no problem populating the cb.  In fact, I use the method below and have even tried using a dictionary.  Both worked.  This is not my issue.

```
cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM States WHERE States.ActiveEntry = true ORDER BY States.State"

        conn.Open()

        Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While rdr.Read()
                cb_State.Items.Add(rdr("State"))
            End While
        End Using

        cb_State.SelectedIndex = -1

        conn.Close()
```

The problem is when I do a subsequent lookup from a different table and I get an ID value for state (based of the table):

StateID   AutoNumber
StateAbbr ShortText
State     ShortText

And in my customers table ...

CustomerID  AutoNumber
...
StateID     Number

So when I load the customer data, I want the state to be selected based on the ID.  I know in HTML I can set the value to the StateID, and if I remember correctly back in VB 6.0 you could add a number to the displayed text that is hidden and search on that.

Now how do I do that today?  It seems that I would have to take my StateID and do a lookup on the State table to get the Name of the State and then use FindString, which IMHO is a very screwy way of doing things.

I tried to create a Dictionary and I could add the Key and Value items as advertised on here (Binding combobox using dictionary as the datasource ([Binding Combobox Using Dictionary as the Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412739/binding-combobox-using-dictionary-as-the-datasource)) which worked the same as above, but for the life of me I could not figure out how to search and set the right state when being populated.

I know I can't be the only one with this issue and I'm sure it's a simple solution, but it evades me.

Comment: Create a new `DataTable` object and pass the reader `rdr` to its `Load` method to fill it with the values from the database. Or use `OleDbDataAdapter` to do so. Bind the combo box: `cb_State.DataSource = dt`, set `cb_State.DisplayMember = "State"`, and `cb_State.ValueMember = "StateID"` and you are done. Now you can get the selected value (StateID) by converting the `cb_State.SelectedValue` to integer.

Comment: Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240192/14171304

Comment: Perfect!  The example is a bit dated but nevertheless, using the example's method of adding the data to the combobox and then applying what you said about the selected value worked.  I figured there had to be a simple way of doing this.  As I had said before, it's been over 20 years since I programmed in VB--a long way from VB for DOS.